# COUNT не работает должным образом

Tags: sql

Всем привет,

Следующий запрос должен выбрать день, количество продаж в этот день и отделы:

```
SELECT
DATE(s.transaction_date) as day,
d.name as department,
COUNT(s.id) as sale_count
FROM sale s
JOIN department d on d.id = s.department_id
group by d.name, s.transaction_date
```

Но он как-то неправильно считает COUNT. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `как-то неправильно считает COUNT` - не кажется вам, сударь, что по этой формулировке нифига не ясно, что это значит?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Вот так выглядит результат: http://imgur.com/a/NWi0h

Comment: А причем тут `count()` он все правильно считает. У вас дата транзакции ведь с временем, раз вы вверху берете от нее `date()` а в `group by` вы почему то date не применяете и группировка идет с точностью до секунды, т.е. по сути группировки нет

Comment: Большое спасибо. Сейчас добавлю ответ с правильным кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря помощи [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) был найден правильный ответ:

```
SELECT
DATE(s.transaction_date) as day,
d.name as department,
COUNT(s.id) as sale_count
FROM sale s
JOIN department d on d.id = s.department_id
group by d.name, DATE(s.transaction_date)
ORDER BY DATE(s.transaction_date) ASC
```